# Reading file with different length lines into linked list (C Programming)

Tags: c, file, struct, linked-list, structure

I need to read an input text file into a linked list that looks like this:

> Greenbelt 1 Green 0
>   College_Park 1 Green 125
>   Prince_George_Plaza 1 Green 300
>   West_Hyatsville 1 Green 450
>   Fort_Totten 3 Green 700 Yellow 0 Red 241
>   Georgia_Ave_Petworth 2 Green 820 Yellow 100
>   Columbia_Heights 2 Green 1000 Yellow 280
>   U_St 2 Green 1180 Yellow 460
>   Shaw_Howard_U 2 Green 1300 Yellow 580
>   Mt_Vernon_Sq 2 Green 1420 Yellow 700
>   Gallery_Place 3 Green 1540 Yellow 820 Red 1612
>   Archives 2 Green 1630 Yellow 910
>   L'Enfant_Plaza 5 Green 1800 Yellow 1080 Blue 1300 Silver 1320 Orange 1400
>   Navy_Yard_Ballpark 1 Green 2200

But the problem Im having is that I cant figure out what to do when there is more than one color metro line. I need to enter it in so that everything following the station name is still connected to that station. My structure is as follows:

```
#define NEW(x) (x*)malloc(sizeof(x))
    typedef struct{
    char * name;
    char * color;
    int number;
    int time;
} STATION;

typedef STATION DATA;

typedef struct node
{ void * data;
    struct node * next;
} NODE;

typedef struct
{ long num;
    NODE * head;
    NODE * tail;
}ROOT;
```

The code that I have been using the successfully will enter only the first four words/numbers in each line.

```
int main(){

    char c, s1[100], *num, *time;
    DATA *data;
    ROOT *root;
    NODE *temp;
    FILE *input, *lines, *report;

    input = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    lines = fopen(argv[2], "w");
    report = fopen(argv[3], "w");

root = make_root();
 while (fscanf(input, "%c", &c) != EOF) {
            data = NEW(DATA);
            if (data == NULL) {
                return -1;
            }

            data->name = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char));

            if (c == '\n') {
                fscanf(input, "%c", &c);
            }

            i = 0;
            do {
                data->name[i] = c;
                i++;
                data->name = (char *) realloc(data->name, (i + 1) * sizeof(char));
                fscanf(input, "%c", &c);
            } while (c != ' ');
            data->name[i] = '\0';

            i = 0;
            num = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char));
            do {
                fscanf(input, "%c", &c);
                num[i] = c;
                i++;
                num = (char *) realloc(num, (i + 1) * sizeof(char));
            } while (c >= '0' && c <= '9');
            data->number = atoi(num);

            i = 0;
            data->color = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char));
            do {
                fscanf(input, "%c", &c);
                data->color[i] = c;
                i++;
                data->color = (char *) realloc(data->color, (i + 1) * sizeof(char));
            } while (c != ' ');
            data->color[i - 1] = '\0';

            i = 0;
            time = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char));
            do {
                fscanf(input, "%c", &c);
                time[i] = c;
                i++;
                time = (char *) realloc(time, (i + 1) * sizeof(char));
            } while (c >= '0' && c <= '9');
            data->time = atoi(time);

insert_at_position(root, data);
}

return 0;
}

ROOT * make_root (void)
{ ROOT * temp;
    temp = NEW(ROOT);
    if (temp != NULL)
    { temp->num = 0;
        temp->head = NULL;
        temp->tail = NULL;
    }
    return temp;
}


int insert_at_position(ROOT *r, DATA *d)
{ NODE * temp, *this;
    temp = make_node(d);

    if (temp == NULL){
        return -1;
    }

    if (r == NULL) {
        r = make_root();
        if (r == NULL) {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    if (r->head == NULL)
    { insert_at_head(r, temp->data);
        return 0;
    }

    this = r->head;
    if (((DATA *)(this->data))->time >= ((DATA *)(temp->data))->time)
        insert_at_head(r, temp->data);

    else
    { while (this->next != NULL &&
             ((DATA *)(this->next->data))->time > ((DATA *)(temp->data))->time)
            this = this->next;

        if (this->next == NULL)     // update tail if insert at tail
        { r->tail = temp;
            this->next = temp;
            (r->num)++;
        }
        else
        { temp->next = this->next;
            this->next = temp;
            (r->num)++;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My question is how can I change my code/structures so that I can put all the station information into a single node so that I can use that information to present metro information later on in my code? Should I add char *color2, int time2, char *color3, int time3 etc... to my struct to accommodate for the stations with extra lines?

I read that I might be able to read in the station name and the number of lines on that station and then create an additional STATION structure for that but I could not find information on how to do so. Any info will help! Thanks!

Comment: Each element of your main linked list needs a separate linked list of colours and numbers.  For the simpler stations, there's only one element in the secondary list; for the complex ones, up to five in the sample data, though once you're processing a list, the length really doesn't matter.  That's an extra structure type: `struct Colour { char name[16]; int number; struct Colour *next; };` and you have a `struct Colour *colour_list` in your main list element in place of the current `colour` member.  Naming up to you; colour seems obvious, but maybe it should be `line` or something else.

Comment: Also, you can use [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getdelim.html) to read an entire line with one line of code, [`strtok()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtok.html) to split the line into tokens, and [`strdup()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strdup.html) to make copies of tokens.  That will make your code a lot simpler and allow you to actually see what's going on.  And `#define NEW(x) (x*)malloc(sizeof(x))` in C code is likely to generate a lot of comments here...